# Combine List Into Dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Bear with me as I'm new to python. I'm iterating through data and getting multiple lists that I need to combine into one pandas dataframe.

I then need to add headers so I can perform calcs.

Problem is each item is being treated as a separate entity. Please help

```
for r in rows:
  person_info = list()
  person_info.append(r['metadata']['name'])
  person_info.append(r['metadata']['CountryId'])
  person_info.append(r['metadata']['StateId'])
  person_info.append(r['metadata']['Income'])
  print(person_info)
```

Here's the output:

```
['mike' , 1, 4, 20000]
['mary', 2, 5, 30000]
['jane', 3, 6, 40000]
```

here's the desired output as a dataframe with the headers "name", "id_a", "id_b", and "income":

```
name    id_a    id_b    income
mike    1       4       20000
mary    2       5       30000
jane    3       6       40000
```

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, feel free to accept, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas accepts a list of dictionaries directly. Don't fight this, you can simply extract `i['metadata']` for each item in your list.

Your only task thereafter is to rename and sort columns.

```
r = [{'metadata': {'name': 'mike', 'CountryId': 1, 'StateId': 4, 'Income': 20000}},
     {'metadata': {'name': 'mary', 'CountryId': 2, 'StateId': 5, 'Income': 30000}},
     {'metadata': {'name': 'jane', 'CountryId': 3, 'StateId': 6, 'Income': 40000}}]

df = pd.DataFrame([i['metadata'] for i in r])\
       .rename(columns={'CountryId': 'id_a', 'StateId': 'id_b', 'Income': 'income'})\
       .reindex(['name', 'id_a', 'id_b', 'income'], axis=1)

print(df)

   name  id_a  id_b  income
0  mike     1     4   20000
1  mary     2     5   30000
2  jane     3     6   40000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable `person_info` outside of loop and append `tuple`s in each iteration:

```
person_info = list()
for r in rows:
  person_info.append((r['metadata']['name'], r['metadata']['CountryId'], r['metadata']['StateId'], r['metadata']['Income']))
```

Solution with `list comprehension`:

```
person_info = [(r['metadata']['name'], r['metadata']['CountryId'], r['metadata']['StateId'], r['metadata']['Income']) for r in rows]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(person_info, columns=["name", "id_a", "id_b", "income"])
```

Another possible solution if input is `json` is use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    

with open('myJson.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

df = json_normalize(data, 'metadata')
```

Comment: I now want to then manipulate the dataframe then convert it back to json and post via api. How do I go about that? Again, bear with my basic questions. For example: js = {
 "name" : "mike"
 "id_a" : "1"
  "id_b" : "4"
  "income" : 40000" 
}

Comment: @nia4life - No problem about basic question. Do you need same format as input data?

Comment: @nia4life - I think need [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), maybe need `df.to_json(file, orient='records')`

Comment: Then get `[{"name":"mike","id_a":1,"id_b":4,"income":20000},{"name":"mary","id_a":2,"id_b":5,"income":30000},{"name":"jane","id_a":3,"id_b":6,"income":40000}]` from your sample data, is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `defaultdict` and using it to create `dataframe`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

person_info = defaultdict(list)

for r in rows:
    person_info['name'].append(r['metadata']['name'])
    person_info['id_a'].append(r['metadata']['CountryId'])
    person_info['id_b'].append(r['metadata']['StateId'])
    person_info['income'].append(r['metadata']['Income'])
```

Then, creating dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(person_info)
```

Comment: Great! that it worked. I would also suggest trying other methods suggested in other answers. `Happy Coding`.